# Recalculate total when table row is deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, row, html-table, delete-row

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joansuriel/QmHdL/50/). What I want is recalculate the total when I delete a row. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
tot -= parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML)
        table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
```

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="lorr">
     <table id="myTable" border="1">
                                
     </table>
     <br />
</div>
<button id="deletes">Remove Checked</button>
<button type="button" onclick="displayResult()">Insert new row</button>    
<div id="total">
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayResult()
    {
    var swap = '<input type="checkbox" class="escondeyou">';
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);    
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = swap+"NEW CELL1ffffffffffffffffff ui7iytuiui riuiui ri";
    cell2.innerHTML = "600";
    cell2.style.fontWeight="bold";
    cell2.style.wordBreak="keep-all";
    var tot = "RD$"+document.getElementById("total").innerHTML;
    // ******************** Important part ******************************
    var tot=0; 
        for(var i=0;i<=rowCount;i++){
        tot += parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);      
    }
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML=tot;
    };


</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

Here is working: http://jsfiddle.net/joansuriel/QmHdL/50/

Comment: Could I do something like "live results"?

Comment: Put the code that sums the values and displays it in a separate function.  Call it on insert and delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your click handler should do without changing too much your code. Note that you can reuse the calcTotal but be carefoul, I loop until i < table.rows.length

```
$('#deletes').click(function(){

    $("table input[type='checkbox']:checked").parent().parent().remove();
    calcTotal(document.getElementById("myTable"), document.getElementById("total"));
});

function calcTotal(table, total){
    var tot = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<table.rows.length;i++){
        tot += parseInt(table.rows[i].cells[1].innerHTML);      
    }
    total.innerHTML=tot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a delete method, just do something with it.

Your code:

```
$('#deletes').click(function(){
  $("table input[type='checkbox']:checked").parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Change to:

```
$('#deletes').click(function(){
  $("table input[type='checkbox']:checked").parent().parent().remove();
  var $table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var total = 0;
  for (var i=0; i < $table.rows.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = $table.rows[i];
    total = total + parseInt(currentRow.cells[currentRow.cells.length - 1].innerHTML);
  }

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total.toString();
});
```

Comment me if you have any question.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but this is not helping me out.@Ares Ou       `function totamt(table,total){
 var table = document.getElementById("stock");
  var total = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<table.rows.length;i++){
       var currentRow = table.rows[i];
    total = total + parseInt(currentRow.cells[currentRow.cells.length - 1].innerHTML);
      }
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total.toString();

} `